# SQL Server slow on executeBatch while trying to update

Tags: java, sql-server, performance, spring-batch

I am having a Spring batch with JDBC template for persistence. The batch job does some processing and at the end of the job is updating some records. We're talking about 5K or more as those can grow with time. The update it takes literally minutes to update 5K of records which is ridiculous. I encountered the same issue with the insert but by adding `-Dspring.jdbc.getParameterType.ignore=true` it speed up the batch insert to some extent so at least this issue is sorted.

As regards to the **batch update** issue, I've been looking around but all optimizations I found online are about Oracle and MySql (truth to be told never had a problem like that with these two). Unfortunately I have to work with the client DB of choice which is SQLServer.

- Tried to get the connection from JDBC template and
  `setAutoCommit(false);` some suggested that this does the trick but
  that didn't work.
- Tried different mssql-jdbc drivers, that didn't    work.
- Tried to tweak with diff settings the db connection, that didn't work.

Below is the latest snipped code which I tried (I had many versions of it but I will post what I am currently trying now as I am writing this post)

```
    public void batchUpdateSingleTable(List<Map<String, ?>> mapArgTypes) throws SQLException {
        SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://mydomain.com:3341;database=my_db;trustServerCertificate=true;encrypt=true;");
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        dataSource.setStatementPoolingCacheSize(10000);
        dataSource.setDisableStatementPooling(false);
        dataSource.setServerPreparedStatementDiscardThreshold(10000);
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);


        String insertSql= "update foo..mytable set name=?  where id=?";
        try (PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql);){
            
            for(Map<String, ?> next : mapArgTypes) {
                prepStmt.setString(1, next.get("name").toString());
                prepStmt.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(next.get("id").toString()));
                prepStmt.addBatch();
            }

            prepStmt.executeBatch();

        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's taking 5 minutes _to perform the update_, but it's hard for anyone here to guess what else is happening. Curious why you're explicitly turning off `AutoCommit` - if you are trying to implement all of the batches as an atomic transaction then you are defeating the purpose of batching. You'll need to tell us what you see in `sys.dm_exec_requests` (look at `wait_type`, `last_wait_type`, and `blocking_session_id`) while you're waiting for 5 minutes.

Comment: Are you updating all items at once? Where is this method used in your spring batch app? Are you using a chunk-oriented tasklet (and with which chunkSize) or a simple tasklet? Please share more details to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine mystery solved. I actually never bother to check the table structure - there's loads of indexes on the table and no primary key. Testing an update on a simple table where you have a primary key, 5k records takes literally 1 second.